# How to find a index of an item in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

But I need the index of the second time appearance.
It is like I have a string "asd#1-2#qwe" 
I can simply use index method to find the index value of first #, which is 3.
But now I wanna get the index of second #, which should be 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `enumerate` and a `list comprehension`:

```
>>> s = "asd#1-2#qwe"
>>> [i for i, c in enumerate(s) if c=='#']
[3, 7]
```

Or if string contains just two `'#'` then use `str.rfind`:

```
>>> s.rfind('#')
7
```

---

Using `regex`: This will work for overlapping sub-strings as well:

```
>>> s = "asd##1-2####qwe"
>>> import re
#Find index of all '##' in s
>>> [m.start() for m in re.finditer(r'(?=##)', s)]
[3, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you. Both ways are useful.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
s = "asd#1-2#qwe"
try:
    s.index('#',s.index('#')+1)
except:
    print "not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the index method to get the first occurrence of #. If the index method allows a starting position, use the position of the first # + 1 for the start. If it doesn't, make a copy of the string starting at position of first # + 1 (possibly a copy and then a substring).

Answer (score 0):

```
a =  "asd#1-2#qwe"

f = '#'

idx = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    if v == f:
        idx.append(i)
print idx
```